# Rosetta, Rosetta Grappelli and Grappelli messages not showing

Tags: django, translation, django-grappelli, django-rosetta

I have a weird issue with this, the messages to be translated do not show on the rosetta url,
Im using django 1.3.1, grappelli 2.3.5, rosetta-grappelli 1.0.1 and rosetta 0.6.5.

As you can see on the following screenshot, it recognizes the language file:

[broken link]

But as you can see in this other screenshot, it shows pagination, but not the messages, which is just weird:

[broken link]

The filter is set to show all --> thats Filtro: Todo

What is missing? should I install latest grappelli? or is just something wrong with my settings?

Comment: Tried without django-rosetta-grappeli ? This will show if it's a template or a rosetta issue.

Comment: Yup seems to be a django rosetta grapelli issue... weird! could it also be the grappelli admin version?

Comment: umm.. in my local development rosetta does'nt load django.po in order to translate.. why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a fix added in this fork https://github.com/jmacul2/django-rosetta-grappelli/

It was just what I needed now the translations in rosetta appear in a django-grappelli theme way.